# How to display a Lightning component from a managed package on clicking button using quick action

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, appexchange, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

I have downloaded a managed package from AppExchange, which is basically a Lightning component. I want to display this component as a quick action in the highlights panel using a button.

When I tried to create an action there, I didn't find the AppExchange component. How to use this AppExchange component in the quick action?

Comment: Doesn't the AppExchange provider have any documentation on how to use their component? Maybe it's not activated to be used as Quick Action. This can be configured by them in the component.

Comment: I'm able to use it as a custom component. But I want to display it once after clicking quick action button.

Comment: Best to ask the app provider. There should be an email address on the listing. Or you could put a review there, asking this question.